# iOS 7 - Custom UISlider design not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider, ios7

Everything works fine in previous version of iOS, but not on iOS 7.
It is not setting custom design for UISlider so there is nothing on the view, the Volume slider view is empty. Everything else works fine.

Code:

```
for (UISlider *slider in volumeSlider.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"Searching!");
        if ([slider isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            NSLog(@"SLIDER FOUND!");
            [slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbSlider.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMax.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
            [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMin.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post this in the Apple forums due to the NDA.

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Nope, I starte using the default UISlider look in iOS 7, and customized slider in iOS6<

Answer (score 5):

iOS7 is now released so the NDA no longer applies.  if you need to support operating systems lower than iOS6 you can use this code.  This works on iOS7 as well.  Note: if you only need to support iOS6 and later there are direct APIs provided by Apple to set these images to customize the look of the MPVolumeView, specifically setVolumeThumbImage:(UIImage *) forState:(UIControlState), setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:(UIImage *) forState:(UIControlState), and setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:(UIImage *) forState:(UIControlState).

```
// replace the standard look and feel for the MPVolumeSlider with custom images
// note: on iOS7 it is necessary to set the thumb image last or the thumb will be drawn under the slider (not pretty), on iOS6 the order didn't seem to matter.
UIView *a = nil;
for (UIView *view in [self.volumeView subviews]) {
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
        a=view;
        UIImage *volumeBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 5, 7, 5)];
        [(UISlider *)a setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:[[ApplicationType sharedInstance] imageForAppType:@"volume_progress"]] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 5, 7, 5)]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [(UISlider *)a setMaximumTrackImage:volumeBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [(UISlider *)a setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_handle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this even works on iOS 5. For iOS 4 you'll just have to get rid of the resizableImageWithCapInsets-Call.

Comment: The thumb was beneath the track in my app on iOS 7, thanks for your comment on setting it last!

Answer (score 0):

Possible Apple has changed some API. If you use this code for volume slider of movie player try to use [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: I am using MPVolumeView

Comment: Understood. Deployment target is less than 6.0. That's why you're searching for the slider.